# How to choose the right iframe with webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, captcha

I am trying to code a click the button of this web captcha what code do I need to press it down?
website: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

I tried:

```
   //Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   IWebElement iframeSwitch = 
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/section/div/div/section/div/article/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/div/iframe"));
   Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeSwitch);
   Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class=recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark]")).Click();
```

**Screenshot:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwvX3.jpg)

Comment: are you trying to select the checkmark in the recaptcha?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you can use to click on the checkbox.

imports needed (for explicit wait)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Code to select the checkbox:**

```
frame = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a']")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.recaptcha-checkbox').click()
```

Comment: i am getting an error i dont this this is for csharp            https://prnt.sc/rq1ujf